# Nested FOR loops - coding challenge

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am learning python using [STEPIK](https://stepik.org/lesson/511170/step/6?unit=503368) and I am facing this:

I want on every iteration of the inside for loop sum the values of `predicted_growth` list with the value of `cases` list, save it in some temporary variable and print it. Click on the link for the full challenge.

This is my code so far:

```
def predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth):
    print()
    result = []
    for i in range(len(cases)):
        for j in range(len(predicted_growth)):
            result = cases[i] + predicted_growth[j]
            print(result, end = " ")
        print()


cases = [12508, 9969, 310595, 57409]
predicted_growth = [100, 200, 300]

predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth)
```

This is the output of the function I should be getting:

```
[12608, 10069, 310695, 57509]
[12808, 10269, 310895, 57709]
[13108, 10569, 311195, 58009]
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
12608 12708 12808 
10069 10169 10269 
310695 310795 310895 
57509 57609 57709
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop with an inner list comprehension.

```
def predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth):
    res = [] # this will hold the results

    for growth_rate in predicted_growth: # outer loop to iterate the growth rate
        prev = res[-1] if res else cases # get the previously computed result, if there is no such result get initial cases (`cases`) as previously computed result
        res.append([growth_rate + i for i in prev]) # list comprehension to add the current growth rate(`growth_rate`) to the previous cases

    for result in res: # iterate through `res` list
        print(result) # print the result

cases = [12508, 9969, 310595, 57409]
predicted_growths = [100, 200, 300]
predict_cases(cases, predicted_growths)
```

Output

```
[12608, 10069, 310695, 57509]
[12808, 10269, 310895, 57709]
[13108, 10569, 311195, 58009]
```

Comment: That's perfect, but to be honest I don't understand most of the lines. I will have to dive into list comprehension. Thank you

Comment: I will add in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You just have your for loops inside out:

```py
def predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth):
    print()
    growth = 0
    for j in predicted_growth:
        growth += j;
        result = []
        for i in cases:
            result.append(growth + i)
        print(result)


cases = [12508, 9969, 310595, 57409]
predicted_growth = [100, 200, 300]

predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth)
```

Output:

```
[12608, 10069, 310695, 57509]
[12808, 10269, 310895, 57709]
[13108, 10569, 311195, 58009]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the order of the nested loops should be reversed in my opinion,as you want to print three lists, corresponding to `len(predicted_growth)` and not four lists, which would correspond to `len(cases)`.

Also, you are creating the variable `result` as a list but then you are overwriting it with a number, which is `cases[i] + predicted_growth[j]`, so it will always print the numbers and never the list containing them.

I got the desired output with the following function:

```
def test(c, p):
    print()
    growth_factor = 0
    result = []
    for i in p:
        growth_factor += i
        for j in c:
            result.append(i + growth_factor)
        print(result)
        result = []
```

Note that you can iterate in a list as it is shown in the `for` loops, without the need of specifying `list[iterator]`, which in this example can be more comfortable in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, now it outputs lists, awesome! but the operation isn't simply addition its increment of a predicted_growth list member and cases. Therefore the step is not always 100 but 100, 200, 300 from the previous sum -- > 
`[12608, 10069, 310695, 57509]
 [12808, 10269, 310895, 57709]
 [13108, 10569, 311195, 58009] `

Comment: You are right, my mistake, I read through my output too quickly. 

I have updated my code with the missing operations in order to get the expected output. You do need a variable which determines the current growth factor in order to properly update the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are inherently iterable, thus `for i in myList:` makes it easier.
List also have the `.append()` method, which builds your list easily.
Then the aforementioned loop swap to get things in your desired order.

```
def predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth):

    for j in predicted_growth:
        result = []
        for i in cases:
            result.append(i + j)
        print(result)

cases = [12508, 9969, 310595, 57409]
predicted_growth = [100, 200, 300]
predict_cases(cases, predicted_growth)
```